# How to run python using ./ from Linux terminal?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, terminal

I have a .py python script and when I run it typing  `./filename.py` I obtain a syntax error. However, when I run it typing `python filename.py` my program executes correctly.

How to make it run correctly typing `./filename.py` ? I think it is related to the $PATH variable but I don't have any further idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put either a shebang at the start of the file, or run with python
for example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

or run:

```
python3 filename.py
```

Comment: Thank you ! The current shebang was  `#!/usr/bin/python` but the correct one is `#!/usr/bin/env python3` as you mentioned.